# How can i group by in LINQ statment and inculude NULL values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to group by "fournisseur.Id" and also get values that have no types or categories

```cs
var result =
    from fournisseur in _context.Fournisseurs
    join type in _context.FournisseurTypeFournisseurs on fournisseur.Id equals type.FournisseurId
    join categorie in _context.FournisseurCategories on fournisseur.Id equals categorie.FournisseurId
    orderby fournisseur.Nom
    select new
    {
        fournisseur.Id,
        fournisseur.Siren,
        Contacts = fournisseur.Agences.Select(a => a.Contacts),
        categorie = fournisseur.FournisseurCategories.Select(a => a.CategorieId),
        type = fournisseur.FournisseurTypeFournisseurs.Select(a => a.TypeFournisseurId),
        fournisseur.Agences,
        fournisseur.Nom
    };

    return Ok(result);
```

i have tried `result = result.DistinctBy(i => i.Id);` but it does not seem work i get an error

Comment: You need to convert your joins to left joins. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: Your `result` is an `IQueryable<Anonymous>` - you need to materialize it first by using `await ToListAsync`. Also, you cannot use anonymous-types (`new { ... }`) as Models in ASP.NET views because you cannot specify them in `@model`.

Comment: Use navigation properties, not join.

Answer (score 0):

use left join and take distinct.

```
var result =
    (from fournisseur in _context.Fournisseurs
    join type in _context.FournisseurTypeFournisseurs on fournisseur.Id equals type.FournisseurId into ft from ftResult in ft.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join categorie in _context.FournisseurCategories on ftResult.Id equals categorie.FournisseurId into cft from cftResult in cft.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby fournisseur.Nom
 
select  fournisseur
).Distinct()
```

I've not tested the above code but had worked on similar functionality.
I've just added the left join part so that it will return all details of Fournisseurs + other table fields

Comment: var result = (from fournisseur in _context.Fournisseurs join type in _context.FournisseurTypeFournisseurs on fournisseur.Id equals type.FournisseurId into ft from ftResult in ft.DefaultIfEmpty()
join categorie in _context.FournisseurCategories on ftResult.Id equals categorie.FournisseurId into cft from cftResult in cft.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby fournisseur.Nom
select fournisseur ).Distinct()